# Can't get result outside the query function in express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to get the value of variable w_name outside query even I have defined `w_name` before query but cannot getting it after query. Please check the code and help:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id=?',[results[0].w_id],function(err,res,field){
                        w_name = res[0].name;
                });
                console.log(w_name);
```

`console.log` showing undefined but if I am putting `console.log` inside the query after `w_name` it is showing proper result. What's wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

`connection.query(...params)` is asynchronous function, which requires some time to read and get resulting data for query passed to it. 
Defining `console.log(w_name)` prints undefined because result is not yet assigned to w_name variable. Whereas defining it inside callback function assigns value to w_name.

Check [this](https://medium.com/@kvosswinkel/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb) article for understanding asynchronous javascript.

```
           connection.query('SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id=?', 
                    [results[0].w_id],function(err,res,field){

                    w_name = res[0].name;
                      console.log(w_name);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs is asynchronous, It uses callback for the results. 
The best solution as far as i know about your problem is given below:

```
async function myQuery(){
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id=?',[results[0].w_id],function(err,res,field){
                    resolve(res[0].name)
            });

     })
}
```

Now you can use `then` to get the value or use `async` `await` to get the value like this.

```
//this is where you would like to call that function.

async function index(){
    let w_name = await myQuery()
    console.log(w_name)
}
```

Comment: async function myQuery(){
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         connection.query('SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id=?',[results[0].w_id],function(err,res,field){
           w_name = res[0].name;
           resolve(w_name)
         });
      
     })
      }
      async function index(){
     w_name = await myQuery()
    }
    console.log(w_name);

Comment: try to print message from within the index function. I have slightly modified my code to reflect the change

Answer (score 0):

here you can use `Promise()` and `resolve()` the query of the result.

```
const w_name = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id=?', [results[0].w_id], function(err, res, field) {
            if (err) throw err
            resolve(res[0].name);
        })
    });
console.log(w_name);
```